# Concatenating three strings to create one string

Tags: vb.net

I've been working on this assignment for class but ran into an issue when creating a string from three other strings. It creates a invoice number based on the first letter in the first and last name and the last 3 numbers of the zip code.

```
Dim split As String() = txtName.Text.Split(", ")
Dim last As String = split(0)
Dim first As String = split(1)

Dim invFirst = first.Substring(0, 1)
Dim invLast = last.Substring(0, 1)
Dim invZip = cityState.Substring(cityState.Length - 3)
Dim invNumber = invFirst + invLast + invZip

lstInvoice.Items.Add("Invoice Number: " + invNumber)
```

Instead of printing out AB123 it will print out just B123. I have tried using + and & and even tired converting all components to a string just to be sure it wasn't trying to treat the values as numbers or something.

Am I missing something like flushing the stream or casting them differently?

Comment: I cannot reproduce this behavior.

Comment: What are the values of `first` and `last`? What happens if you use explicit types (`Dim invFirst As String`) and `String.Concat`?

Comment: 'first' and 'last' are simple strings like John and Smith. When I use 'Dim invFirst As String' or 'String.Concat', it returns the same way it has been @Dai

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Split() returns an array. https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/tabh47cf(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1

So you need to trim the strings. And then it will work.
https://dotnetfiddle.net/U5gvh5

```
Dim split As String() = txtName.Split(",")
Dim last As String = split(0).Trim()
Dim first As String = split(1).Trim()
```

Comment: That seemed to have worked. First time using Split() so that one caught me off guard. I assume it was actually seeing `first` but because there was a comma then a space it only saw the space without trimming. `Smith, John` would have been what was input so I thought putting `", "` would have taken care of the space.

Comment: @Ross Presser: Thank you for the edit. But now I'm confused. The MSDN link has the section "The separator array" and they show what happend if you have a 2-Char-string as a separator. So my Trim() doesn't make sense anymore. The original code should work. IMHO It seems like a .NET bug?!